# iCal and Google Calendars - Same Grouping

Tags: google-calendar, calendar.app

Okay, I just started using iCal because I wanted to sync my Google Calendars to my local machine and allow it to deal with the new Notifications system built in Mountain Lion.

What I want to do: Sync multiple Google Calendars with iCal on OS X Mountain Lion.

What I have setup on Google Calendars:

- Personal
- Work
- Meetings

I would like them to be consistent in iCal such as:

- Google

  - Personal
  - Work
  - Meetings

Rather than what shows up which is them being under different headers when I subscribe to them separately (Making new calendar accounts for each and each appearing under www.google.com or Google or calendar.google.com) such as:

- Google

  - Personal
- www.google.com

  - Work
- calendar.google.com

  - Meetings

And not under Delegates which is stupid and shows:

- Delegates

  - Work

    - Work
  - Meetings

    - Meetings

Has anyone had any experience or is this impossible to have some sane consistency in syncing multiple calendars because I think it's ridiculous to have a design as either of the above styles.

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem, and found this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4372 (however it doesn't work for me, but worth trying anyway)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I too saw that page but it didn't work for me either :( I think it would only help if I were using the mobile version of iCal. Thanks though!